# Upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 when 10.10 was installed using Wubi

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, windows, dual-boot, wubi

I had installed Ubuntu 10.10 using wubi so I could dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu.
Now I am upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 using the upgrade option provided within Ubuntu itself (using the update manager).

Will this in any way affect my Windows and other files on my HDD?
I hope the installation of the new packages automatically will not format my D drive i.e. I hope this automatic update will not make a clean install by formatting all the data in my hard disk.

This might sound like a silly question, but I just want to double check while the upgrade files are being downloaded.

Thanks,
Zeiger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be fine. I just did that a few weeks ago. It just does it's thing and all your files will be unaffected. Everything stays in your Wubi virtual partition. Nothing is formatted and it does not affect Windows in any way. :)

Comment: Thanks @Fuddledumpy what you said is exactly what happened